# Why I get undefined when I try to access the value of the session id from the cookies

Tags: reactjs, session, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to access the value of the sessionid from my cookies and I get undefined even tho the sessionid is set in the cookies.

My application uses React and for this particular task, I'm using Cookies from js-cookie.

Here is my code

```
import {urls} from "../../Urls";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export async function updateUser (body) {
  let headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "X-CSRFTOKEN":Cookies.get("csrftoken"),
    "sessionId":Cookies.get("sessionid")
  }

  await fetch (process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_END_DOMAIN + urls.PROFILE,{
    method:'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers : headers,
  });
}
```

And here is how the cookie looks like
[image]

However, when I console.log both the csrftoken and the sessionId, the csrftoken works as expected while the sessionid is undefined.
Any explanation for this?